# Browser variable not working on include?

Tags: php, variables, browser, include

Okay so I have a code which says

```
if (!$num_users || $num_users !== 1 ) {
include_once('../assets/scripts/error.php?error=404');
exit();
}
```

and it doesn't seem to work, I get the error

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

but if I change the include line to

```
include_once('../assets/scripts/error.php');
```

it works. I need to have the `?error=404` on the end to tell the page to echo out that type of error message. Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!$num_users || $num_users !== 1 ) {
    $error_type = 404;
    include_once('../assets/scripts/error.php');
    exit();
}
```

And then in error.php, use the variable `$error_type` if it is defined

Answer (score 1):

That's really not how things work.  ?error=404 is a parameter that would be passed through an HTTP server while parsing the PHP code.  `include` literally just takes the contents of the named file and inserts them into the current file right here.  You can set a variable $error before the include, and then you can get access to it in the included file.